# How do I customize the notification message in django-oscar notification system

Tags: django-oscar

How do I customize the notification message that displayed on the accounts/notifications

there is something missing on this page , the body of the notification is displayed like this :-

`<a href="/catalogue/test-product_6/">test product</a>` is back in stock

instead of being a clickable link to the product

I tried to edit the message.html template but there is no changes happen

I just need to know in the template customer/notifications/detail.html
the {{ notification.body }} is coming from which template ?

what should I do to fix this link

Note: the email that is sent to the user got the correct link and i'm able to customize it through the communications events from the database
is there any option to customize the notification templates from the database too?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notification is rendered from `customer/notifications/detail.html` as you state.

The issue is that there is HTML being passed to the body of the notification, but the template is [rendering it as an unsafe string](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/blob/f2bb0fb73c83cb879fb2dec9184059dd96d814e0/src/oscar/templates/oscar/customer/notifications/detail.html#L29) (i.e., the HTML gets escaped).

This looks like a bug in Oscar, which I've made an [issue](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/issues/2916) for.

In the mean time you will need to override this template to change this:

```
<td>{{ notification.body }}</td>
```

to:

```
<td>{{ notification.body|safe }}</td>
```